# Node.js memory usage never decrease

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, express, memory-leaks

I've already finished my first small project in node.js and now came time for performance testing using apache benchmark (1000 requests with 50 concurrency). Everything seems to be ok, hundred of requests handled per second, super fast, no failed request, just perfect. Unfortunately there is one really wired issue...the memory usage of a process keeps increasing, so lets say the memory usage is 10% just before  apache benchmark will have finished his job and after that job is done it still remains at the same level - 10% than decreasing to some low level (this is how I expect garbage collector should work). Is that normal node behaviour or I've made some memory leaks in my app (I even test it with the **no logic** API endpoint but it still happens)? Thanks in advance for any tip. I can even share my whole app code base with someone interested in that problem.

Comment: The v8 GC is lazy, how long are you checking the memory usage and how are you checking the memory usage (e.g. RSS)?

Comment: @mscdex I run the apache benchmark test with 10000 requests, concurrency 50. The memory usage was on the same level during the whole test time but after the test has been done the memory still seems to be allocated than deallocated (still keep the 12.7% usage https://www.dropbox.com/s/qj2o9io7q3vx76b/Screenshot%202014-09-08%2000.20.45.png?dl=0). I was waiting more than 30 mins (no requests were comming to the server at that time - testing locally on virtual machine) and unfortunately no deallocation happened, the process still keeps 12.7%. Any idea what's going on and why?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to make snapshots before making requests and after using [this module](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump). After that just [check](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump#inspecting-the-snapshot) which extra objects have been created and whether they are yours. Dont' forget to use Comparison mode in dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a blog that may help you to identify this with chrome dev tools and heapdump module.

http://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-performance-tip-of-the-week-memory-leak-diagnosis/